# what does the 'Q' in QUnit stand for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I'm currently brainstorming for possible names on some JavaScript modules I'm working on, and was looking for ideas. I came across QUnit and was wondering what the 'Q' stands for, since the info doesn't appear to be available on its [home page](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit). Is it "Query" for example, or maybe "quick" like in [QBASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QUnit is the jQuery unit testing suite.  The `Q` most logically derives from `jQuery` just like you said.

Comment: Makes sense. What leaves me confused is that jqGrid
http://www.trirand.com/blog/
 is prefixed with "jq".

Comment: @T. Webster, I don't think you can compare QUnit to jqGrid for naming since QUnit is an official part of jQuery and jqGrid is a third-party plugin.